# PowerShell - Delete a Range of Rows from Excel After Locating Starting Row

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a PowerShell script that searches an Excel file for a specific value ("#N/A", from a failed VLOOKUP) that needs to have all of the rows AFTER and including that row deleted quickly.

What I have done so far:

```
$sheetRange = $sheetData.UsedRange
$colRange = $sheetData.Range("F1")
[void] $sheetRange.Sort($colRange)
$fileWorking.Save()

$strFinder = "#N/A"
$rngSearch = $sheetData.Range("F1").EntireColumn
$txtFound = $rngSearch.Find($strFinder)
$RowFound = ($txtFound.Row)
for (($i = $RowFound); ($i -le $rowsTrans); $i++)
{
  $currRow = $sheetData.Cells.Item($i).EntireRow
  [void]$currRow.Delete()
}
$fileWorking.Save()
```

The problem is, there are over 200k rows, and I need to **delete the entire range** instead of one row at a time.  While I have muddled around with the syntax some, I can't quite figure out the proper syntax or methods that accomplish this.

Obviously, the `for` loop simply needs to go, and I need to set the entire range between `$RowFound` and `$rowsTrans`... but how is that done?

Comment: Can you construct a concatenated string containing all of the addresses then use that to delete? e.g. `...Range("A2, A4, A10, A19").entireRow.Delete` That uses a range object definition much like a union of range objects.

Comment: @Jeeped My syntax, when assigning a "group" range was wrong.  I figured it out on my own, but your answer is in the same vein as my mistake.  I was trying to do ...Range("A"+$RowFound+":A"+$rowTrans)   (note the ":").  Would you reform your comment into an answer to correct my syntax as described, and I'll accept?  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct a concatenated string containing all of the addresses as you run through the [Range.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) loop. Use that to define the [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) with the [Range.EntireRow property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836836.aspx) to [.Delete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834641.aspx).

```
...Range("A2, A4, A10, A19").EntireRow.Delete
```

That uses a range object definition much like a [Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834621.aspx) of range objects.

Comment: Perfect solution.  I should point out I'm doing a `sort` process early on, so I always know everything AFTER and including the first entry needs to be deleted, but your solution is even better if a sort hasn't been done, or isn't reliable (as in, I need to find possible values, and they may not be in order).  Definitely above and beyond what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

I know this is super old, but I found an even better way to do this with a one-liner. This article sparked my months long journey to this single line... lol

```
Measure-Command { $sheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCellType]::xlCellTypeFormulas, 16).EntireRow.Delete() } #finds any row with an #N/A and blows it away
```

[Referenced from here.](https://www.myfaqbase.com/q0001773-Scripting-Powershell-Working-with-Microsoft-Office-Excel-part-1.html)

The comment says what it does, but it searches the ENTIRE file for any cell with #N/A. I'm sure there is a way to make this even more efficient by narrowing to a single column. Hopefully this helps someone like me that couldn't get the range command to work!

BTW, this lowered my deletion times from 12-15 hours to 30 minutes on a ~30,000 line file.